# Tools or Software for Text Analysis

Tags: gratis, data-analysis, language, text

Does anyone know of or use (preferably free) tools or software that allow you to search in text documents for certain words, and then add an identifying code to them for later analysis?

It would also be beneficial if the software can visually code the text documents and produce frequency analysis.

Comment: Welcome to Software recommendations! It looks like this question is about natural language analysis, so I added a tag for that. I recommend adding more context about your question, since not everyone on this site will be familiar with NL text analysis, and it will certainly be interpreted differently here than on the psychology site it was migrated from.

The good news is, there are probably a fair number of non-psychologist community members who are familiar with NL, and may be able to answer your question.

Comment: https://monkeylearn.com/blog/text-analysis-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misinterpreting the question, I think you just need a text editor with search/replace feature.  This includes every text editor as far as I know.   Just set up search to find your word and replace it with the word + your code.  If you want your code to be control characters or something unusual, you might have to look around some or find a means of displaying controls characters as text.

I also think there are some that display counters as to the number of finds if that is what is meant by frequency analysis.

hope this helps,    tom kosvic

Comment: I think that the OP wants to search multiple documents at the same time, and it sounds like they want to annotate the documents without modifying the original text.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not quite clear. For example, what do you mean by "add an identifying code"? Tom's answer suggests Search&Replace to include a code. Is that what you mean?

Here is a possible alternative but again, it is not quite clear what you have in mind:
Try **[EmEditor](https://www.emeditor.com/)**. It is a sophisticated text/code editor that allows you to search in one or more documents for a string and then

- extract the string (or the lines containing that string) into a separate document, or
- bookmark the lines and then manage the bookmarks (next, previous, clear, etc.) within the document.

You can then repeat the process for different strings, adding to the found results.
The program displays a count of the found strings - a sort-of pseudo frequency analysis. There is a free and a paid version.